# how to get the volumelabel for the current console prompt

Tags: windows, batch-processing, drive

for example my volumelabel for driveletter **e** is **volume-abc**

so for example im in the shell at:

```
e:\directory-a\bc\>
```

now i need the volumelabel of driveletter **e:**, with the statement:

```
vol %CD:~0,1%:
```

i will get the current volumelabel, but with a bunch around it ( sorry, only in german ):

```
Datenträger in Laufwerk E: ist volume-abc
Volumeseriennummer: 4A69-FD21
```

so maybe it is possible to parse / extract the string volume-abc from this output, but it seems for me like a bad way, because the output could be vary from windows- and language-version. so i dont know how to do that string operation in robust way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET volume=%1
IF NOT DEFINED volume SET volume=%CD%
SET "volume=%volume:~0,1%:"
SET "vlabel="
SET "vserial="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('vol %volume%') DO (
 CALL :lastparm %%a
)    
ECHO LABEL is %vlabel%
ECHO Serial is %vserial%
endlocal&set vlabel=%vlabel%&set vserial=%vserial%
GOTO :EOF

:lastparm
SET $1=%2
IF DEFINED $1 shift& GOTO lastparm
IF DEFINED vlabel (SET vserial=%1) ELSE (SET vlabel=%1)
GOTO :eof
```

This should do what you request - within limits. Run the batch, providing you drivename as the first parameter. If no parameter is provided, the current drive will be chosen.

In English, the response from `VOL` may be

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 830B-46FA

 Volume in drive M is XPC
 Volume Serial Number is 62FF-EBB1
```

So it would seem that a language-independent version may be a little difficult. The above code would give `label.` for `C:`, not `no label.` What any other language would generate, I've no idea.

It could be however that the fact that the response is in lower-case may be a way of defining "unlabelled" - I believe a real label must be upper-case.

And it appears that a volume label may now be up to 32 characters, and I've no idea whether spaces are now allowed...

Edit : added `ENDLOCAL` line to set values found in caller's environment. The method doesn't seem logical at first glance, but exploits the parsing procedure used by `cmd`. The entire `endlocal` line is parsed and `%var%`s replaced by their contents. Then the line is executed, which first disposes of all environment updates made since the `setlocal` and then assigns the values of interest back to the variables.

Comment: thank you very much! is there a way to include this as a own script and use the variables in a main script? like: call your-posted-script-in-batch-file.bat && echo vlabel: %vlabel%